# I am facing '__init__(): incompatible constructor arguments.' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, tensorflow

I am trying object detection machine learning through Tensorflw; was following a video by
Nicholas Renotte. A year old video and while running the trainning module to covert my xml and jpg file into record files I ran into this error. Tried alot of things and now stuck on what to do next.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import argparse

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
from collections import namedtuple

# Initiate argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Sample TensorFlow XML-to-TFRecord converter")
parser.add_argument("-x",
                    "--xml_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input .xml files are stored.",
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument("-l",
                    "--labels_path",
                    help="Path to the labels (.pbtxt) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-o",
                    "--output_path",
                    help="Path of output TFRecord (.record) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i",
                    "--image_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input image files are stored. "
                         "Defaults to the same directory as XML_DIR.",
                    type=str, default=None)
parser.add_argument("-c",
                    "--csv_path",
                    help="Path of output .csv file. If none provided, then no file will be "
                         "written.",
                    type=str, default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.image_dir is None:
    args.image_dir = args.xml_dir

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    return label_map_dict[row_label]


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(args.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(args.image_dir)
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    print('Successfully created the TFRecord file: {}'.format(args.output_path))
    if args.csv_path is not None:
        examples.to_csv(args.csv_path, index=None)
        print('Successfully created the CSV file: {}'.format(args.csv_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

This is the error I am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\Codes\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 114, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 76, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(filename: str, buffer_size: int, token: tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.TransactionToken = None)

Invoked with: item {
  name: "Hello"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "ILoveYou"
  id: 2
}
item {
  name: "no"
  id: 3
}
item {
  name: "yes"
  id: 4
}
item {
  name: "thanks"
  id: 5
}
, 524288
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\Codes\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\scripts\generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 114, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\Kanna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 76, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(filename: str, buffer_size: int, token: tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.TransactionToken = None)

Invoked with: item {
  name: "Hello"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "ILoveYou"
  id: 2
}
item {
  name: "no"
  id: 3
}
item {
  name: "yes"
  id: 4
}
item {
  name: "thanks"
  id: 5
}
, 524288
```

Comment: As a general rule for stack overflow: Please provide a minimal code example. If you can reduce your problem to a few lines of code, this will make it much easier for other users to comprehend your code, idenfity the issue, post a solution and learn from it afterwards. We're here to solve specific programming problems and make the solutions accessible to everyone on the internet after all, not to fix someone else's tutorial series.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the [command line arguments](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9864) when calling the `model_main_tf2.py` script to train the model.

In your command line arguments, change `--pipeline_config` to `--pipeline_config_path`